# ImportError when importing Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to test GUI code using Python 3.2 with standard library Tkinter but I can't import the library.

This is my test code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The shell reports this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
from Tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

Comment: This was wrongly closed. The original duplicate was about Tkinter being missing on some installations of Python. This one is about the change in the module's name (from uppercase to lowercase t) from Python 2 to Python 3. However, I found a more comprehensive duplicate that is actually specific to the question, and also has a better title for future viewers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The root of the problem is that the Tkinter module is named `Tkinter` (capital "T") in python 2.x, and `tkinter` (lowercase "t") in python 3.x.

To make your code work in both Python 2 and 3 you can do something like this:

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *
```

However, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) has this to say about wildcard imports:

> Wildcard imports ( from <module> import * ) should be avoided

In spite of countless tutorials that ignore PEP8, the PEP8-compliant way to import would be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

When importing in this way, you need to prefix all tkinter commands with `tk.` (eg: `root = tk.Tk()`, etc). This will make your code easier to understand at the expense of a tiny bit more typing. Given that both tkinter and ttk are often used together and import classes with the same name, this is a Good Thing. As the [Zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states: "explicit is better than implicit".

Note: The `as tk` part is optional, but lets you do a little less typing: `tk.Button(...)` vs `tkinter.Button(...)`

Answer (score 20):

The module is called `tkinter`, not `Tkinter`, in 3.x.

Answer (score 10):

Rewrite the code as follows with `Tkinter` as `tkinter` (lowercase) for 3.x:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```