# How to get Tkinter working on mac

Tags: python, tkinter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ImportError when importing Tkinter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498658/importerror-when-importing-tkinter-in-python)

I have a Mac with Mountain Lion installed on it. I want to dev for Python on it, so I grabbed a Python 3.3 release candidate and started to work with it. However, I was trying to start working with Tkinter graphics, and when I tried this line:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Eclipse (and IDLE) gave me this nasty error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/venkatsmoorthy/Documents/workspace/Python/python/tkinterGUI/tkinter_1.py" line 7, in <module>
from Tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

I don't wan't to downgrade. I am willing to though, but only to 3.2.3. Please don't make me do it.

I did google around, and figured out that OSX has some problem with Tkinter. I tried a few solutions, but no dice. Please answer with your own instructions for how to get tkinter working on python 3.3/3.2.

Comment: as a matter of fact I have. It was the solution I tried. However, it's not working. Everything throws the same errors. Is there some special import I should be using?

Comment: No, there's only one kind of import. Python 3 calls it `tkinter` not `Tkinter` -- is that the problem?

Comment: YES, THANK YOU! I was looking at a website where the import command is listed as import Tkinter, and so I was operating under the impression that it had to be that command. Have an upvote.

Comment: Awesoem -- I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Python 3 calls it `tkinter` not `Tkinter`.