# ImportError: cannot import name 'SliceType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python 2.x program with this line of code:

```
from types import SliceType
```

When running the file with `python3`, the following error is printed:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SliceType'
```

How can I fix this so both Python 2.x and Python 3.x can execute the file?

This is **not** a duplicate of any random other `ImportError` question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498658/importerror-when-importing-tkinter-in-python). It is intended to be found via Google/SO search when you got the same error message. Before writing this question/answer, I wasn't able to find any solution for the issue described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try`-based construct to get full 2.x/3.x compatibility:

```
try:
    from types import SliceType
except ImportError:
    SliceType = slice
```

See [this reference](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html) for a table on the Python3 names for objects in the Python2 `types` module.