# Python import/from issue

Tags: python-3.x, import, tkinter

I am writing a python GUI script and I have a problem with the import/from.

I find the I can not delete one of the lines above as the script will not work. Therefore, why and is there a way to make this shorter?

script:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import  asksaveasfilename, askdirectory
from tkinter import ttk
...
```

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation on using modules](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Where did you get the idea that making code shorter by removing working lines makes it better?!

Comment: Well, `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import *` aren't both necessary unless the code uses both `button = Button(root)` and `label = tkinter.Label(root)`, which it shouldn't, but sounds like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `import tkinter`, then you must prefix all tkinter commands and constants with `tkinter.` (eg: `buttontkinter.Button(...)`, `root=tkinter.Tk()`, etc).

When you do `from tkinter import *`, it imports everything that tkinter has marked as exportable, and you do *not* prefix things with `tkinter.` (eg: `button=Button(...)`, `root=Tk()`, etc)

*You should do one or the other, not both.* Preferably, do the former. To make for a little less typing you can import with an alias, for example:

```
import tkinter as tk
...
root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, ...)
```

Note that this isn't a tkinter-specific problem. This is fundamentally how importing all modules in python works.

Also note that, while `ttk` is in `tkinter`, it doesn't get imported when you do `from tkinter import *`. Also, ttk will export classes with the same name as tkinter (for example: they both define `Button`)

For more information, read [the documentation on modules](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html) in the python documentation. You might also want to read the answers to [ImportError when importing Tkinter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7498658/7432)